# How to parse answer from RPC::XML in perl

Tags: perl, xml-rpc

I`m sending RPC::XML request and getting proper reply. But don't know how to parse the response in a proper way. Here is my code:

```
use RPC::XML;
use RPC::XML::Client;

my $value = "something";

my $rpc_value = RPC::XML::string->new($value);
my $req = RPC::XML::request->new('service.makeGood',$rpc_value, $URL);

my $client = RPC::XML::Client->new($CLI);
my $responce =$client->send_request($req);
```

When I do Dumper for response, I see the following:

```
$VAR1 = bless( [
             bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'RPC::XML::boolean' ),
             bless( do{\(my $o = 'some reply')}, 'RPC::XML::string' )
           ], 'RPC::XML::array' );
```

How I can parse the value of `bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'RPC::XML::boolean' )` ? So I need to see if its true of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `value()` method on the data structure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does. The value() method returns an equivalent perl data structure, so the boolean value may be get directly from the 1st element of the array. There's no need in parsing the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

value() - works.

Also instead of **send_request()** can be used **simple_request()** that returns array of values.
The following variants are equal:

```
my $responce = $client->send_request($req);
my $value = @$responce[0]->value();
```

or

```
my $responce = $client->simple_request($req);
my $value =  @$responce[0];
```